# Leaf in binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

How can i build a function that get the root of binary tree and find the highest leaf
(the leaf that is closest to the root)

you can use n.left/n.right/n.parent

assume there is only one leaf that is the highest leaf

Comment: Use BFS. It is traversing the tree in a way, that first the higher nodes are visited. So the first leaf you find will be the highest one (or one of the highest ones)

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse the tree, looking for leafs and keeping track of their depth finding the highest.
In general there are two primary methods of traversing trees:
[BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and
[DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

Both can be used here. BFS will find find the heighest leaf faster as it traverses the tree in levels finishing one level before going down to the next. While DFS will likely traverse almost all of the tree before it can be stopped, even if the highest lead isn't very deep.

On the flip side, DFS is easier to implement and uses less memory, so if you have small trees and/or don't care about runtime and need to implement from scratch use DFS. If you have severe memory constraints use BFS. If you can afford O(N) extra memory and want to find the answer as fast as possible, use BFS.